# Client-Server Program: Client can connect to server easily but server can't respond cause target machine actively refuses connections

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, client

I am trying to write a client-server program for the first time. It works fine on LAN networks but I can't get it to work over internet.

I can easily send data to the server program with the following code:

```
public static bool sendTo(IPEndPoint ip, String data)
    {
        using (TcpClient c = new TcpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                c.Connect(ip);
                NetworkStream clientStream = c.GetStream();
                ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
                byte[] buffer = encoder.GetBytes(data);

                clientStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                clientStream.Flush();
                c.Close();
            }
            catch
            {
                c.Close();
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
   }
```

Then server has to respond to the client using the same code but it fails giving the following error:

No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it *IP*:*PORT*

I know the problem can be fixed with port-forwarding and changing the settings of router. But I'll probably try to make a software out of this soon and users should be able to use the software with minimal configurations. So... I was wondering if anyone can help me here...

Thanks in advance,
eLe

Comment: If you have clients communicating with a server then you want to preserve the TCPClient (or Socket) that you accept with [AcceptTCPClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.accepttcpclient.aspx) (or AcceptSocket) when the client first connects and use that to send data to the client. It would be inefficient if nothing else to re-establish the TCP Connection every time you want to send any data. Depending on your other requirements you may find that you need multiple threads on the server (one per client) unless you plan on using non-blocking reads.

Answer (score 0):

You need to design your client and server so that the client-to-server connection remains open to recieve the responce and then do something like this:

```
public static bool sendTo(IPEndPoint ip, String data)
{
    TcpClient client = null;
    NetworkStream stream = null;
    StreamWriter writer = null;
    StreamReader reader = null;

    try
    {
        client = new TcpClient();
        client.Connect(ip);
        stream = c.GetStream();
        writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
        writer.WriteLine(data);
        writer.Flush();

        reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        string response = reader.ReadLine();

        if (response == "roger-alpha-tango")
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (writer != null) writer .Dispose();
        if (reader != null) reader .Dispose();
        if (stream != null) stream.Dispose();
        if (client != null) { client.Close(); client.Dispose(); }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but Isn't there a way in which i can close the sending function immediately after sending the data and listen to another port for responses with another function? 

You know... My main problem is more on listening to a port on client and not the sending part. 

If there isn't any way, I should try your method.

Comment: @I.Admiration You need to keep hold of the `TCPClient` if you want to send data to the client, store it in a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) of IPs, if you want. How do you keep track of clients internally?